# Get value from list of nested dict in Python based on key

Tags: python

I have a list of dict, need to get the int_value from the sub-dict of values based on the value of the key.

```py
my_list = [{'key': 'previous_id',
  'value': {'int_value': '-4343583665607944462'}},
 {'key': 'event_origin', 'value': {'string_value': 'auto'}},
 {'key': 'screen_id', 'value': {'int_value': '-5880567181845583757'}},
 {'key': 'previous_class', 'value': {'string_value': 'MainActivity'}},
 {'key': 'screen', 'value': {'string_value': 'Gateway'}},
 {'key': 'screen_class', 'value': {'string_value': 'Gateway'}}]
```

For example, I need to get -4343583665607944462 as a string output for previous_id.

This is what I got so far, which looks over complicated to me, want to know if there is more straightforward way to achieve that.

```py
for d in my_list:
    if list(d.values())[0] == 'previous_id':
        print(list(d.values())[1].values())
```

Get -4343583665607944462 as a string output for previous_id.

Please also suggest if define a function would make sense.

Comment: `for dict_ in my_list:..if dict_['key'] == 'previous_id':....yield dict_['value']['int_value']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be worth while to preprocess your initial list of dicts, something like:

```
key_to_int = {}
for d in my_list:
    if 'int_value' in d['value']:
        key_to_int[d['key']] = d['value']['int_value']
    else:
        key_to_int[d['key']] = None
```

You can then simply do:

```
print(key_to_int['previous_id'])
print(key_to_int['event_origin'])
print(key_to_int['screen_id'])
```

Which outputs:

```
-4343583665607944462
None
-5880567181845583757
```

The above assumes all your dicts follow the same format. In the case where some dicts may be nested deeper than others, some modifications need to be made.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up making a method to preprocess the list with input of list and value type, so that I can use the same to get int_value and string_value.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggestion checking if the first value is `"previous_id"` by using the `"key"` key rather than `.values()[0]`, and same for getting the value. If you know the keys ahead of time, this is the recommended way of accessing data from a dictionary.

If you want to simplify your code, you could use the `next` function, which loops over an iterable and returns the first value it finds (that matches the given condition if there is one).

For example:

```
value = next(d["value"] for d in my_list if d["key"] == "previous_id")
```

This would return

```
{'int_value': '-4343583665607944462'}
```

If you want just `"-4343583665607944462"`, then you could do:

```
value = next(list(d["value"].values())[0] for d in my_list if d["key"] == "previous_id")
```

Note here we use `.values()[0]` because the keys are not always the same.

Also `next` raises a `StopIteration` exception if it reaches the end of the iterable without finding a match so consider wrapping it in a `try`/`except` block.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have access to modifying the actual list beforehand, but it would probably make more sense to keep the type of value inside a single dict e.g:

```
my_list = [{
    'key': 'previous_id',
    'value': '-4343583665607944462',
    'type': 'int_value' },...]
```

This way you could simply call:

```
for dict in my_list:
    if dict['key']=='previous_id':
        return dict['value']
```

or a one-liner:

```
value = [x['values'] for x in my_list if x['key']=='previous_id']
```

and if you are keen on having the value type

```
value = {x['type']:x['values'] for x in my_list if x['key']=='previous_id'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like use the same dictionary and stick with your method, you can use:

```
for d in my_list:
    if d["key"] == 'previous_id':
        print(list(d["value"].values())[0])
```

But would recommend you to use a dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = {"previous_id": '-4343583665607944462', 'event_origin':'auto',  
    'screen_id':-5880567181845583757,  'previous_class': 'MainActivity',
    'screen': 'Gateway',  'screen_class': 'Gateway'}
```

Then you can use print simply like this:

```
print(my_dict["previous_id"])
```